# Meteor: Intro Page App Android / iOS (Viewpager)

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I wanted to know if there is a component such as Viewpager, create an Intro Page in the App.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search on google

Comment: I found JQuery-Mobile, but it is no longer supported by Meteor, I did not find anything on Google (Viewpager / Silde)

Comment: https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/make-android-viewpager-intro-screen-page-transformer-animation/

Comment: I saw how it does, but I can do this with Android Studio, with Meteor how do you do it?